# Can't add an Alert Action to UIAlertController (Swift)

Tags: swift, alert, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I'm trying to add an Ok button to a UI Alert but I cannot add it using alertController.addAction

What do I do in this case?

Thanks in advance!!

```
if error == nil {
                let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Account Created", message: "Please confirm your email", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMain", sender: self)

                    alertController.addAction(okButton)


                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

                } else {

                println("\(error)")
            }
```

Comment: its alert.addaction..not alertcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `alert` instead of `alertController`
2. `alert.addAction` should be outside of your `okbutton` action.

Change your code with :

```
if error == nil {
    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Account Created", message: "Please confirm your email", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMain", sender: self)

    }
    alert.addAction(okButton)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 } else {

            println("\(error)")
        }
```